# Convert bytedata into pdf image

Tags: flutter

I want to convert a bytedata to a pdf image .But the output is only a blank image.I tried so many ways but it doesn't work.

This is my code that given ,

```
List<int> buildPdf(PdfPageFormat format) {
    final image = PdfImage(doc.document,
        image: widget._customerSign.buffer.asUint8List(),
        width: 20,
        height: 20);

    final images = PdfImage(doc.document,
        image: widget._managerSign.buffer.asUint8List(), width: 20, height: 20);

    doc.addPage(`
      pdf.Page(
        orientation: pdf.PageOrientation.portrait,
        pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
        build: (pdf.Context context) {
          return pdf.Column(
            children: <pdf.Widget>[
              pdf.Text(
                '${widget.headline}',
                style: pdf.TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
              ),
              pdf.SizedBox(height: 10),
              pdf.Text(
                '${widget.details}',
                style: pdf.TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
              ),
              pdf.SizedBox(height: 35),
              pdf.Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: pdf.MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <pdf.Widget>[
                    pdf.Image(image),
                    pdf.Image(images),
                  ])
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
//

    return doc.save();
  }
}
```

I want to convert a bytedata to a pdf image .But the output is only a blank image.I tried so many ways but it doesn't work.

Comment: signature is given as bytedata it is given in a container and save it .i want to print the signature in a  pdf page

Comment: I mean that when i given the signature (widget.customersign) in to the pdf image is not working

Comment: i will explain detaily, in my service app project page there is a contract page that design to allow to sign for customer and manager.so i take only one container to sign both signature ,the container key is given as 'sign'.then i save the signatures by a save button ,the code i given is,

Comment: FlatButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            final sign = _sign.currentState;
         
            final image = await sign.getData();
            var data = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
            sign.clear();
            final encoded = base64.encode(data.buffer.asUint8List());

            setState(() {
              _img = data;

              print( "image is $_img");

            });

            debugPrint("onPressed " + encoded);

Comment: _img.buffer.lengthInBytes == 0
                ? Container()
                : Navigator.pop(context, _img);

Comment: then the 'data' is saved automatically when signed and show it in a container by passing the data ,finally i want to print the signature in to a pdf format

Comment: pass bytedata customersign to the pdf image constructor

Comment: final image = PdfImage(doc.document,
        image: widget._customerSign.buffer.asUint8List(),
        width: 20,
        height: 20);